# Which programming language is used at the Large Hadron Collider?

Tags: time-complexity, programming-languages

First off I am new to computer science (first semester) and do not know anything about physics, so I am appologizing up front for this not very scientific question.

I've been wondering how data is processed at the `LHC`. I am sure `CERN` doesn't just use one programming language to write code but I am curious what the fastest (machine nearest?) language is, keeping in mind that particles at `LHC` are nearly moving at the speed of light.

So if for example a sensor senses a particle on one side of the `LHC`, and there is a sensor on the other side of the LHC, data from one side to the other would have a direct and shorter way, but the processing would have to take less than a 50 millionth of second (est.), right?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the model at CERN is to generate huge amounts of data at the experiment sites and then store it for later processing. I'm not aware of any requirement to process and transmit data from one side of the accelerator to the other, in real-time, while experiments are going on.

Comment: There is also the possibility that some of the preprocessing runs in hardware (or at least programmable hardware).

Comment: While the data processing CERN does is certainly interesting, questions about their technology are hardly ontopic here. That said, I'm sure they publish significant parts of if (them being scientists and all); questions about *specifics* of what they do can be valid questions for this site. Even then, you may be better off on [scicomp.SE], [statistics.SE] or [physics.SE], depending on the question.

Comment: yes there are big challenges with "big data" and moving/processing massive amts of data. one of the central areas of efficiency focus is algorithms that process images/tracks and attempt to separate out "interesting" from "noninteresting" tracks... ie events that one wants to analyze vs pictures without the event being searched for. think there are some fast/optimized image processing algorithms for all that. yes think general algorithms in use here are on topic for this site & think its too bad/pity theres next to nothing on LHC/Higgs etc right now on this CS site esp given CS pivotal role.

Comment: I remember seeing job ads from CERN. In those ads, they were mostly looking for people knowing C++, Python, and/or MATLAB.

Comment: looking a bit over on [physics.se] among much stuff they also use [geant](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32059/use-of-monte-carlo-simulation-in-high-energy-physics) an open source Monte Carlo track simulator. there is some misconception in the question, they digitize a lot of pictures over extended periods of time and post-process the data after experiments run, there is not too much realtime processing afaik except maybe to reject/screen/filter "obviously uninteresting" stuff/nonevents. there is also a lot of use of statistical methods etc.

Comment: started physics chat on it & already some [feedback](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14558633#14558633) _cool!_

Comment: This question as written would be off topic for us on [physics.SE], but a more general question about how the LHC detectors keep up with all that data might be on topic there. We do welcome questions about the design of major physics experiments.

Comment: @vzn thanks for putting the question to the chat. The reply by [dmckee](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14562445#14562445) pretty much states what I was looking for.

Comment: sure :) ... they also mention they use FPGAs at times for high speed selection filters. unf have never seen CS-centric surveys of their setups which are quite CS-heavy in many ways. hope some good refs eventually emerge some day. they also mention [ROOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROOT) for data analysis.